# Immutable @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

Is it possible to have immutable (final) fields with Spring Boot's `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation? Example below

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "example")
public final class MyProps {

  private final String neededProperty;

  public MyProps(String neededProperty) {
    this.neededProperty = neededProperty;
  }

  public String getNeededProperty() { .. }
}
```

Approaches I've tried so far:

1. Creating a `@Bean` of the `MyProps` class with two constructors

   - Providing two constructors: empty and with `neededProperty` argument
   - The bean is created with `new MyProps()`
   - Results in the field being `null`
2. Using `@ComponentScan` and `@Component` to provide the `MyProps` bean.

   - Results in `BeanInstantiationException` -> `NoSuchMethodException: MyProps.<init>()`

The only way I have got it working is by providing getter/setter for each non-final field.

Comment: To my knowledge, what you are trying to do will not work out of the box.

Comment: That's sad. Of course, I can always do it with plain Spring by using constructor parameters with `@Value` annotation. However, it would be nice if Spring Boot supported this, too.

Comment: I took a small peak at the source code, but it seams non-trivial to support something like what you are asking. Of course I am no expert on Spring internals so I might be missing something obvious

Comment: It's not exactly what you're looking for, but this existing Spring Boot issue may be of interest: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1254

Comment: The solution proposed in the comments would solve my issue too. If the setters were not visible, the configuration properties would be unmodifiable without resorting to violence :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From Spring Boot 2.2, it is at last possible to define an immutable class decorated with `@ConfigurationProperties`.
[The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.constructor-binding) shows an example.
You just need to declare a constructor with the fields to bind (instead of the setter way) and to add the [`@ConstructorBinding`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConstructorBinding.html) annotation at the class level to indicate that constructor binding should be used.
So your actual code without any setter is now fine :

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "example")
public final class MyProps {

  private final String neededProperty;

  public MyProps(String neededProperty) {
    this.neededProperty = neededProperty;
  }

  public String getNeededProperty() { .. }
}
```

Comment: Note that you now have to use the `@ConstructorBinding` annotation to make this work. Before that (RC1) you had to use the `@ImmutableConfigurationProperties` in stead. For more information about why this annotation was chosen, you can refer to [issue 18563](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18563).

Comment: @g00glen00b Thanks for your comment. I updated with the current way to do that.

Comment: On Spring Boot 3.x you no longer should/can use `@ConstructorBinding` for a single constructor. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0.0-M2-Release-Notes#constructingbinding-no-longer-needed-at-the-type-level

Answer (score 17):

I have to resolve that problem very often and I use a bit different approach, which allows me to use `final` variables in a class.

First of all, I keep all my configuration in a single place (class), say, called `ApplicationProperties`. That class has `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation with a specific prefix. It is also listed in `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation against configuration class (or main class).

Then I provide my `ApplicationProperties` as a constructor argument and perform assignment to a `final` field inside a constructor.

Example:

**Main** class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationProperties.class)
public class Application {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**`ApplicationProperties`** class

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class ApplicationProperties {

    private String someProperty;

    // ... other properties and getters

   public String getSomeProperty() {
       return someProperty;
   }
}
```

And a class with final properties

```
@Service
public class SomeImplementation implements SomeInterface {
    private final String someProperty;

    @Autowired
    public SomeImplementation(ApplicationProperties properties) {
        this.someProperty = properties.getSomeProperty();
    }

    // ... other methods / properties 
}
```

I prefer this approach for many different reasons e.g. if I have to setup more properties in a constructor, my list of constructor arguments is not "huge" as I always have one argument (`ApplicationProperties` in my case); if there is a need to add more `final` properties, my constructor stays the same (only one argument) - that may reduce number of changes elsewhere etc.

I hope that will help

Comment: That's a lot of boiler plate vs. just using @Value

Comment: This is [tag:Java]. More boilerplate means better code

Comment: @Clijsters I honestly can't tell if you're being facetious but I mean, its not quite right but its not far off either!

Comment: Yes! It was meant to be facetious (but there is often somethin real about a joke).

Answer (score 3):

Just an update on the latest support of more recent Spring-Boot versions:

If you're using a jdk version >= 14, you can use `record` type which does more or less the same as the Lombok version but without Lombok.

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "example")
public record MyProps(String neededProperty) {
}
```

You can also use record inside the `MyProps` record to manage nested properties. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72718055/628006).

Another interesting post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66696829/628006) which shows that the `@ConstructorBinding` annotation is even not necessary anymore if only one constructor is declared.

Answer (score 2):

Using similar approach to the one from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60442151/11770752

But instead of `AllArgsConstructor` you can use the `RequiredArgsConstructor`.

Consider following `applications.properties`

```java
myprops.example.firstName=Peter
myprops.example.last-name=Pan
myprops.example.age=28
```

*Note*: Use consistency with your properties, i just wanted to show-case that both were correct (`fistName` and `last-name`).

---

Java Class pickping up the properties

```java
@Getter
@ConstructorBinding
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myprops.example")
public class StageConfig
{
    private final String firstName;
    private final Integer lastName;
    private final Integer age;

    // ...
}
```

---

Additionally you have to add to your build-tool a dependency.

*build.gradle*

```
    annotationProcessor('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')
```

or

*pom.xml*

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

---

If you take it one step further to provide nice and precise descriptions for you configurations, consider creating a file `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json` in directory `src/main/resources/META-INF`.

```json
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "myprops.example.firstName",
      "type": "java.lang.String",
      "description": "First name of the product owner from this web-service."
    },
    {
      "name": "myprops.example.lastName",
      "type": "java.lang.String",
      "description": "Last name of the product owner from this web-service."
    },
    {
      "name": "myprops.example.age",
      "type": "java.lang.Integer",
      "description": "Current age of this web-service, since development started."
    }
}
```

(clean & compile to take effect)

---

At least in IntelliJ, when you hover over the properties inside `application.propoerties`, you get a clear despriction of your custom properties. Very useful for other developers.

This is giving me a nice and concise structure of my properties, which i am using in my service with spring.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, if you want an immutable object you can also "hack" the setter that is

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class ApplicationProperties {
    private String someProperty;

    // ... other properties and getters

    public String getSomeProperty() {
       return someProperty;
    }

    public String setSomeProperty(String someProperty) {
      if (someProperty == null) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
      }       
    }
}
```

Obviously if the property is not just a String, that is a mutable object, things are more complicated but that's another story.

Even better you can create a Configuration container

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class ApplicationProperties {
   private final List<MyConfiguration> configurations  = new ArrayList<>();

   public List<MyConfiguration> getConfigurations() {
      return configurations
   }
}
```

where now the configuration is a clas without

```
public class MyConfiguration {
    private String someProperty;

    // ... other properties and getters

    public String getSomeProperty() {
       return someProperty;
    }

    public String setSomeProperty(String someProperty) {
      if (this.someProperty == null) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
      }       
    }
}
```

and application.yml as

```
myapp:
  configurations:
    - someProperty: one
    - someProperty: two
    - someProperty: other
```

Comment: I think you meant `if (this.someProperty == null) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
      }`

Comment: Your design is not immuteable, it's just guarded against setting twice ie. at point A in time the properties could have a different state than at point B.

Comment: [patrickf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774398/patrickf) you are right, in fact I used the term "immutable" improperly. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: That's bad, if people read setXXX(), they expect to be able to change the property. This is not an immutable, it's just a bad bean, which, potentially, will waste time in understanding what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to encapsulate property groups via inner classes and expose interfaces with getters only.

Properties file:

```
myapp.security.token-duration=30m
myapp.security.expired-tokens-check-interval=5m

myapp.scheduler.pool-size=2
```

Code:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("myapp")
@Validated
public class ApplicationProperties
{
    private final Security security = new Security();
    private final Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();

    public interface SecurityProperties
    {
        Duration getTokenDuration();
        Duration getExpiredTokensCheckInterval();
    }

    public interface SchedulerProperties
    {
        int getPoolSize();
    }

    static private class Security implements SecurityProperties
    {
        @DurationUnit(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
        private Duration tokenDuration = Duration.ofMinutes(30);

        @DurationUnit(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
        private Duration expiredTokensCheckInterval = Duration.ofMinutes(10);

        @Override
        public Duration getTokenDuration()
        {
            return tokenDuration;
        }

        @Override
        public Duration getExpiredTokensCheckInterval()
        {
            return expiredTokensCheckInterval;
        }

        public void setTokenDuration(Duration duration)
        {
            this.tokenDuration = duration;
        }

        public void setExpiredTokensCheckInterval(Duration duration)
        {
            this.expiredTokensCheckInterval = duration;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("{ ");
            sb.append("tokenDuration=").append(tokenDuration);
            sb.append(", expiredTokensCheckInterval=").append(expiredTokensCheckInterval);
            sb.append(" }");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    static private class Scheduler implements SchedulerProperties
    {
        @Min(1)
        @Max(5)
        private int poolSize = 1;

        @Override
        public int getPoolSize()
        {
            return poolSize;
        }

        public void setPoolSize(int poolSize)
        {
            this.poolSize = poolSize;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{ ");
            sb.append("poolSize=").append(poolSize);
            sb.append(" }");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    public SecurityProperties getSecurity()     { return security; }
    public SchedulerProperties getScheduler()   { return scheduler; }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{ ");
        sb.append("security=").append(security);
        sb.append(", scheduler=").append(scheduler);
        sb.append(" }");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Lombok annotations the code would looks like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "example")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ConstructorBinding
public final class MyProps {

  private final String neededProperty;

}
```

Additionally if you want to Autowire this property class directly and not using `@Configuration` class and `@EnableConfigurationProperties`, you need to add `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` to main application class that is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

See related documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-constructor-binding

Comment: Not bad in term of clarity except you rely on the Lombok external dependency, IMHO the new `record` feature of Java 14 is a better solution now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to slice test your properties in your application without loading the whole spring boot context use the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` in your test.

Example:

`src/main/resources/application.yml`

```yaml
myApp:
  enabled: true
  name: "test"
```

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myApp")
public class MyApplicationProperties {

    boolean enabled;
    String name;

}
```

```java
// this will only load MyApplicationProperties.class in spring boot context making it fast
@SpringBootTest( classes = MyApplicationProperties.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
class MyApplicationPropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    MyApplicationProperties myApplicationProperties ;

    @Test
    void test_myApplicationProperties () {
        assertThat(myApplicationProperties.getEnabled()).isTrue();
        assertThat(myApplicationProperties.getName()).isEqualTo("test");

}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set the field values through `@Value` annotations. These can be placed directly on the fields and don't require any setters:

```
@Component
public final class MyProps {

  @Value("${example.neededProperty}")
  private final String neededProperty;

  public String getNeededProperty() { .. }
}
```

The downside of this approach is:

- You'll need to specified the fully-qualified property name on each field.
- Validation doesn't work (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44007492/1523648))

Comment: This won't work. You'll get a `needProperty might have not been initialized` error.. One solution would be to use a constructor with `@Value("${example.neededProperty}")  String neededProperty` as a parameter and then initialize neededProperty