# Spring Boot - making configuration final

Tags: java, configuration, spring-boot, final

My Spring Boot (1.3.5) application uses externalized configuration using an `application.properties` file. Alongside, I currently have a configuration class as such:

```
@Configuration
MyConfig {
   @Value("${prop}")
   private String prop;

   // getters
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to make `prop` final. Ideally I'd like to access my configuration properties publicly; for example `myConfig.prop`. I'd like to make all properties *public* and *final*; however I believe configuration classes are first instantiated via an empty constructor before properties are loaded. Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: Why?  What is your concern at runtime?

Comment: It's not a runtime concern; rather it's to avoid inadvertent changes by other devs to the config.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject your config values in the constructor and assign to a `final` field.

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {
  private String final prop;
  public MyConfig(@Value("${prop}") String prop){
    this.prop = prop;
  }

 }
```

Comment: Yes that works. What if I have lots of configuration? I guess that is incentive to split it up into smaller config classes?

Comment: @user1491636 yes, you can do that, DBConfig and SMTPConfig can go into different config classes

Comment: So after making this change, I get a startup exception: `No default constructor found;`

Comment: It's `private final String prop;`, not `private String final prop;`.

Answer (score 0):

For all the people landing here and asking themself the same question, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57191291/11770752

In addition you can use this with *lombok* if desired, which reduces the class' boilerplate code.

Comment: The solution won't work for Spring Boot version 1.3.6 (specified in the question).

Comment: you are right, just in case anybody for new versions (assuming which is the most part of the user) was curious i wanted them to provide further information.

if this is somewhat bad, i'll excuse myself.