# How to add int validation on configuration value in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, max, min

In my `Spring Boot` application, I have a class that uses a value from the configuration file:

```
@Service
public class Cat{

  @Value("${cat.maxAge}")
  private int maxAge;
....
```

I like to add validation on the `Min` and `Max` values, so the app will fail if some wrong values are in the config file.

Trying to do so:

```
@Service
public class Cat{

  @Value("${cat.maxAge}")
  @Max(value=10)
  private int maxAge;
....
```

And IntelliJ doesn't know what `@Max` is and doesn't recognize any package to import for it.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Add `spring-boot-starter-validation`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the needed dependecy in you build.

If you are using `gradle.build` the add this line to `dependencies` like the following

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.6.3'
```

If you are using make sure to add this dependency as the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now the import is added `javax.validation.constraints.Max`, but when putting values outside of the min/max, the app is just ignoring the constraints and starts with no problem - while I was expecting it to give errors.

Comment: Am not sure that this is the issue as am not an expert with spring, But I do believe that you need to change the `@service`, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007492/enforce-constraints-on-value-annotated-field-in-spring-boot-application) might help.
because the usage of @Min and @Max is very straightforward