# How to protect @ConfigurationProperties classes from changes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configurationproperty

To use `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation one must create a class with getters and setters like that:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some")
public class PropertiesConfig {
    private boolean debug;

    public boolean isDebug() {
        return debug;
    }

    public void setDebug(boolean debug) {
        this.debug = debug;
    }
}
```

But this leads to the situation when somebody is tempted to modify this value by calling:

```
@Autowire
private PropertiesConfig config;        
//....

config.setDebug(true);
```

Is there a way to create `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated classes without setters and external parser/reader classes?

Answer (score 6):

From Spring Boot 2.2, it is at last possible to define immutable class decorated with `@ConfigurationProperties`.  Really thanks to Spring developers to improve continuously their framework.
[The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-constructor-binding) shows an example.
You just need to declare a constructor with the fields to bind (instead of the setter way)  :

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some")
public class PropertiesConfig {
    private boolean debug;

    public AcmeProperties(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;   
    }

    public boolean isDebug() {
        return debug;
    }

}
```

Note 1 : you have to define one and only one  single constructor with the parameters to bind  :

> In this setup one, and only one constructor must be defined with the
>   list of properties that you wish to bind and not other properties than
>   the ones in the constructor are bound.

Note 2 : a `@DefaultValue` was introduced to define default values of an immutable property binding.

> Default values can be specified using @DefaultValue and the same
>   conversion service will be applied to coerce the String value to the
>   target type of a missing property.

Here is a more detailed example get from the official documentation :

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.DefaultValue;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBinding;

@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("acme")
public class AcmeProperties {

    private final boolean enabled;

    private final InetAddress remoteAddress;

    private final Security security;

    public AcmeProperties(boolean enabled, InetAddress remoteAddress, Security security) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.remoteAddress = remoteAddress;
        this.security = security;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() { ... }

    public InetAddress getRemoteAddress() { ... }

    public Security getSecurity() { ... }

    public static class Security {

        private final String username;

        private final String password;

        private final List<String> roles;

        public Security(String username, String password,
                @DefaultValue("USER") List<String> roles) {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.roles = roles;
        }

        public String getUsername() { ... }

        public String getPassword() { ... }

        public List<String> getRoles() { ... }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

One approach with as little boilerplate code as possible would be using an interface with getters only

```
public interface AppProps {
    String getNeededProperty();
}
```

and getting rid of boilerplate getters and setters in the implementation with the help of Lombok's `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations :

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "props")
@Getter
@Setter
public class AppPropsImpl implements AppProps {
    private String neededProperty;
}
```

Then, for the bean bo be accessible to other beans only by interface, one can, instead of marking it as `@Component` or using `@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppPropsImpl.class)` on the main application class, consider putting it into a configuration which will expose it by interface:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class PropsConfiguration  {
    @Bean
    public AppProps appProps(){
        return new AppPropsImpl();
    }
}
```

Now this bean can be injected only by using an interface, and this makes the setters not available to other beans:

```
public class ApplicationLogicBean {
    @Autowired
    AppProps props;

    public void method(){
        log.info("Got " + props.getNeededProperty());
    }
}
```

Tested with Spring Boot 1.5.3 and Lombok 1.16.16.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this works fine

```
@Configuration
class MyAppPropertiesConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some")
    public PropertiesConfig propertiesConfig () {
        return new PropertiesConfigImpl();
    }

    public interface PropertiesConfig {
            public boolean isDebug();
    }

    private static class PropertiesConfigImpl implements PropertiesConfig {
        private boolean debug;

        @Override
        public boolean isDebug() {
            return debug;
        }

        public void setDebug(boolean debug) {
            this.debug = debug;
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
@Autowired PropertiesConfig properties;
```

Comment: I had to move the Interface to it's own file.  Then this worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible out of of the box. `@ConfigurationProperties` beans have to have standard getters and setters. You might want to consider the approach described in this answer: [Immutable @ConfigurationProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137932/immutable-configurationproperties)

Or something like this:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationProperties {

  private final String property1;
  private final String property2;

  public ApplicationProperties(
    @Value("${some.property1"}) String property1,
    @Value("${some.other.property2}) String property2) {
    this.property1 = property1;
    this.property2 = property1;
  }

  //
  // ... getters only ...
  //

}
```

Comment: There are a couple of corner cases which, unfortunately, don't work with this approach. For instance, injecting an object from the `application.yaml` as `Map<String, Object>` with `@Value` won't work while it works as expected with the `@ConfigurationProperties` approach.