# How to use @ConfigurationProperties with Records?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-16, java-record

Java 16 introduced [Records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395), which help to reduce boilerplate code when writing classes that carry immutable data. When I try to use a Record as `@ConfigurationProperties` bean as follows I get the following error message:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("demo")
public record MyConfigurationProperties(
        String myProperty
) {
}
```

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.MyConfigurationProperties required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.
```

How can I use Records as `@ConfigurationProperties`?

Comment: How should this work when you also need a @Configuration annotation when those cannot be final but Records are?

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek you can define it in EnableConfigurationProperties config instead of using Configuration annotation

Comment: Thank you @AndreiG, the "instead of" is the key words here.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The above error raises from Spring Boot not being able to construct the bean because of the lack of a no-argument constructor. Records implicitly declare a constructor with a parameter for every member.

Spring Boot allows us to use the `@ConstructorBinding` annotation to enable property binding by constructor instead of setter methods (as stated in [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.constructor-binding) and the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137932/immutable-configurationproperties)). This also works for records, so this works:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("demo")
@ConstructorBinding
public record MyConfigurationProperties(
        String myProperty
) {
}
```

Update: As of Spring Boot 2.6, using records works out of the box and `@ConstructorBinding` is not required anymore when the record has a single constructor. See the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#records-and-configurationproperties).

Comment: I get an error saying that it's final and it should not be final when I use exactly this method. What could be the problem?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 did you find a solution to that? I have the same issue.

Comment: I found a solution, add @ConfigurationPropertiesScan to your main Application class

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue with spring boot 3.0.0 and `@ConstructorBinding` is deprecated.

I needed to add:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class Application
```

Comment: Although the old `@ConstructorBinding` is deprecated, the replacement annotation has the same name.  So we went from `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBinding` to `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.ConstructorBinding`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConstructorBinding.html

Comment: @Atorian Yes. However, we can use the alternate annotation only on a Constructor but not on Application properties class.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to declare default values programatically:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties("demo")
public record MyConfigurationProperties(String myProperty) { 
    
    @ConstructorBinding
    public MyConfigurationProperties(String myProperty) {
        this.myProperty = Optional.ofNullable(myProperty).orElse("default");
    }
}
```

`java.util.Optional` properties:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties("demo")
public record MyConfigurationProperties(Optional<String> myProperty) {

    @ConstructorBinding
    public MyConfigurationProperties(String myProperty) {
        this(Optional.ofNullable(myProperty));
    }
}
```

`@Validated` and `java.util.Optional` in combination:

```java
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties("demo")
public record MyConfigurationProperties(@NotBlank String myRequiredProperty,
                                        Optional<String> myProperty) {

    @ConstructorBinding
    public MyConfigurationProperties(String myRequiredProperty, 
                                     String myProperty) {
        this(myRequiredProperty, Optional.ofNullable(myProperty));
    }
}
```

Based on this [Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27141).

Comment: Do you know how you can use records to declare complex parameters and have the properties follow the hierarchical structure like it would for non record classes?

Comment: I don't recall anything specific about that case, doesn't regular nesting of records work?

Comment: For me these solutions are not working at all :/

Comment: I have the exact same issue, I don't think nesting works ...

Comment: Indeed it doesn't work. I've created a new issue on spring boot github tracker https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28797

Comment: I got it to work by using `@EnableConfigurationProperties` instead of `@Configuration`. Also I did not use `@Validated` - I just did the validation in the constructor.

Comment: The first one can't work at all. You can't create an alternative constructor for a record that has the same types as the native one (in this case a single String). How should Java differentiate between these two? If I do something like **new** **MyConfigurationProperties("TEST")** which one is to chose then?

Answer (score 4):

##### `ConstructorBinding` and compact form of constructor in Spring Boot 3.1.0

As of 'spring-boot' version '3.1.0':

- Annotation `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBinding` is deprecated and can't be applied to type declaration (class, interface, enum, or record), but can be applied to constructor declaration
- Annotation `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.ConstructorBinding;` can't be applied to type declaration (class, interface, enum, or record), but can be applied to constructor declaration

Thus, we can declare `record` and apply `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.ConstructorBinding` **to the compact form of constructor** which is still looks concise:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties
public record ApplicationProperties(/* Your properties here. E.g.:
                                    String prop1, 
                                    Integer prop2, 
                                    NestedConfig nestedProps
                                    */) {

    @ConstructorBinding
    public ApplicationProperties {
    }

}
```

**Note**: Don't forget to enable support for `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated beans in your application. E.g.:

```java
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationProperties.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: This works for me in Spring Boot 3.1.1. Its important to make sure you remove the Configuration from the record.

Comment: This works for me in Spring Boot 3.2.1 and works fine without @ConstructorBinding annotation at record constructor.

Comment: Same, @ConstructorBinding is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

With spring boot 3.0.4, I have been able to use the records directly without any @ConstructorBinding annotation.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
@Validated
public record ApplicationProperties(String version, FtpProperties ftp) {
    public record FtpProperties(
                            @NotEmpty String host,
                            @Positive int port,
                            @NotEmpty String username) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When mapping YAML configuration using the class approach, there is no problem if you use the @Configuration annotation.

However, when switching to using record for mapping, Spring will inform you that it is a final type and cannot be proxied and managed in the container.

I have found that you can explicitly declare in the main class of Spring using @EnableConfigurationProperties(XXProperties.class) or @ConfigurationPropertiesScan that you need to add the class with the @ConfigurationProperties annotation to the container, regardless of whether it is a class or record.

In version 2.x of Spring Boot, if you want to use the record type to map YAML files, you need to add the annotation @ConstructorBinding to the class. However, in version 3.0 of Spring Boot, this is no longer necessary and it has been marked as deprecated.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-295483/Spring-Boot-ConfigurationProperties-annotated-java-record-is-reported-as-not-used

```java
@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableConfigurationProperties(YmlConfigDbProperties.class)
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class AppMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppMain.class, args);
    }

}
```

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config.db")
//@Configuration
public record YmlConfigDbProperties(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spring-Boot 2.7.5 you will only have to

1. Annotate the record with `@ConfigurationProperties`
2. Annotate the Main Class with `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan({RecordConfig.class})`. This part is important as this tells Spring the specifics of the Config class and helps it register as a bean`enter code here`.

Answer (score 0):

I use Spring boot `3.2.2`, so I hadn't to to add most of the things mentioned in another answers

Here is what I did:

1. Created AppConfig, configuration class

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({KafkaProperties.class})
public class AppConfig {
   public static final String KAFKA =  "kafka";
}
```

2. Created KafkaProperties, configuration prop class

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = AppConfig.KAFKA)
public record KafkaProperties(String autoStartup,
                              Topics topics) {

    public record Topics(String name) {

    }
}
```

That's all I need to add and everything if working fine.

Note: need to have naming consistency in Java and application.prop/yaml file