Parameter 0 of constructor required a bean, but not found
I am following along with a Spring Boot demo and they have the following code. File #1 is at com.example.SpringRestDemo.config.RsaKeyProperties.java:
package com.example.SpringRestDemo.config;

import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rsa")
public record RsaKeyProperties(RSAPublicKey publicKey, RSAPrivateKey privateKey) {

}

File #2 is at com.example.SpringRestDemo.security.SecurityConfig.java :
package com.example.SpringRestDemo.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import com.example.SpringRestDemo.config.RsaKeyProperties;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWK;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys;

    public SecurityConfig(RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys) {
        this.rsaKeys = rsaKeys;
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager users() {
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                User.withUsername("chaand")
                        .password("{noop}password")
                        .authorities("read")
                        .build());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        var authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return new ProviderManager(authProvider);
    }


    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaKeys.publicKey()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaKeys.publicKey()).privateKey(rsaKeys.privateKey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("removal")
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/token").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/test").authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
                // TODO: remove these after upgrading the DB from H2 infile DB
                http.csrf().disable();
                http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

        return http.build();
    }

}

The only change I made was adding @SuppressWarnings("removal") above the securityFilterChain method.
When I start up the app it fails with:
PS C:\Users\Lucky\Downloads\SpringRestDemo\SpringRestDemo>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\Lucky\Downloads\SpringRestDemo\SpringRestDemo'; & 'C:\Users\Lucky\.vscode\extensions\redhat.java-1.31.0-win32-x64\jre\17.0.11-win32-x86_64\bin\java.exe' '@C:\Users\Lucky\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_3712j1v86elkflmioerv7939l.argfile' 'com.example.SpringRestDemo.SpringRestDemoApplication' 
AppData\x5cLocal\x5cTemp\x5ccp_3712j1v86elkflmioerv7939l.argfile' 'com.example.SpringRestDemo.SpringRestDemoApplication' ;6d9aa28d-d88b-4842-a18d-7137f9dd18fd  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.0)

2024-06-18T14:38:22.726-04:00  INFO 5092 --- [SpringRestDemo] [           main] c.e.S.SpringRestDemoApplication          : Starting SpringRestDemoApplication using Java 17.0.11 with PID 5092 (C:\Users\Lucky\Downloads\SpringRestDemo\SpringRestDemo\target\classes started by Lucky in C:\Users\Lucky\Downloads\SpringRestDemo\SpringRestDemo)
2024-06-18T14:38:22.734-04:00  INFO 5092 --- [SpringRestDemo] [           main] c.e.S.SpringRestDemoApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-06-18T14:38:26.162-04:00  INFO 5092 --- [SpringRestDemo] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-06-18T14:38:26.186-04:00  INFO 5092 --- [SpringRestDemo] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-06-18T14:38:26.189-04:00  INFO 5092 --- [SpringRestDemo] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.24]
2024-06-18T14:38:26.355-04:00  INFO 5092 --- [SpringRestDemo] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-06-18T14:38:26.359-04:00  INFO 5092 --- [SpringRestDemo] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3438 ms
2024-06-18T14:38:26.476-04:00  WARN 5092 --- [SpringRestDemo] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authController' defined in file [C:\Users\Lucky\Downloads\SpringRestDemo\SpringRestDemo\target\classes\com\example\SpringRestDemo\controller\AuthController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'tokenService' defined in file [C:\Users\Lucky\Downloads\SpringRestDemo\SpringRestDemo\target\classes\com\example\SpringRestDemo\service\TokenService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig' defined in file [C:\Users\Lucky\Downloads\SpringRestDemo\SpringRestDemo\target\classes\com\example\SpringRestDemo\security\SecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.SpringRestDemo.config.RsaKeyProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2024-06-18T14:38:26.484-04:00  INFO 5092 --- [SpringRestDemo] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-06-18T14:38:26.513-04:00  INFO 5092 --- [SpringRestDemo] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-06-18T14:38:26.566-04:00 ERROR 5092 --- [SpringRestDemo] [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.SpringRestDemo.security.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'com.example.SpringRestDemo.config.RsaKeyProperties' that could not be found.       


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.SpringRestDemo.config.RsaKeyProperties' in your configuration.

PS C:\Users\Lucky\Downloads\SpringRestDemo\SpringRestDemo> 

Any ideas how to fix this?

Annotate RsaKeyProperties with @Component?

Better annotate with @Configuration, since this ist the correct way to go. Another way would be to annotate with @ConfigurationPropertiesScan, at least for Spring Boot v2.2+.

Tried all three, none worked, unfortunately.

what's your application.yaml file?

with @SprintBootApplication annotation have you provided any custom packages to look for beans, it might happen that this package is not being considered for bean creation.

@m.antkowicz I don't have one. I have a application.properties file, though.

@Vihar  Unsure what you mean

As you are using Java record as a bean of configuration properties you should enable the constructor binding. This can be done by adding @ConfigurationPropertiesScan to your configuration class. Preferably in your main application class. Like this:
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70081041/14294053

That may have worked but if it did it uncovered another error, 'Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jwtEncoder' defined in class path resource [com/example/SpringRestDemo/security/SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoder]: Factory method 'jwtEncoder' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey.getModulus()" because "pub" is null'
