# How to use records for @ConfigurationProperties in Spring Boot 2.6.4 (class may not be final)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-record

I have a pretty vanilla Spring Boot v2.6.4 Java application, using Java 17.

I am trying to get records to work for my @ConfigurationProperties, but having little success.

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBinding;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom")
@ConstructorBinding
public record CustomConfigProperties(String path) { }
```

This fails with:
`org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: @Configuration class 'CustomConfigProperties' may not be final. Remove the final modifier to continue.`

Obviously, records are implicitly final, so I am stumped. No amount of googling yields anything useful. The closest I could find was this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696828/how-to-use-configurationproperties-with-records) question, but it's not really directly related Infact a commenter on there has the same issue as me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Configuration` should be used on a class that defines beans via `@Bean` methods. Annotating with `@Configuration` triggers the creation of a CGLib proxy to intercept calls between these `@Bean` methods. It is this proxying attempt that is failing because the record is implicitly final.

You should remove `@Configuration` from your record and then [enable your `@ConfigurationProperties` record](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.x/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.enabling-annotated-types) using `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` or `@EnableConfigurationProperties(CustomConfigProperties.class)`. You can also remove `@ConstructorBinding` as records are implicitly constructor bound. `@ConstructorBinding` need only be used on a record if the record has multiple constructors and you need to indicate which constructor should be used for property binding.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful information. Just a minor note: I believe it is `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` not `@ConfigurationPropertyScan`

Comment: You’re right. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

It works if I explicitly annotate my main Application class with:

`@ConfigurationPropertiesScan`

Which is ridiculous since a plain old class style works without this annotation.