# How to create Record from application.yaml in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, record

We are creating APIs using spring boot and there are some configurations that would supply as env in the docker container ad below:

```
config:
   host: ${HOST}
   apiKey: ${API_KEY}
```

I need this host and API key in my service class to make an external API call.

Is there any way to create `Record` class directly from application.yaml as below in Spring boot?

```
public record Config(String host, String apiKey){}
```

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for, not sure if it works on a record or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot

Comment: [configurationproperties-with-records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696828/how-to-use-configurationproperties-with-records)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Main class add `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan`

Create class like this and this should work

```
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "config")
public record Config(String host, String apiKey) { }
```

Or if you want also default settings

```
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "config")
public record Config(String host, String apiKey) {

    @ConstructorBinding
    public Config(String host, String apiKey) {
        this.host = Optional.ofNullable(host).orElse("localhost");
        this.apiKey = Optional.ofNullable(apiKey).orElse("secret");
    }
}
```