# Spring immutable Bean from property file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

In a kotlin/spring boot project, I can create a bean from a property file with this syntax

```kotlin
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.awesome.prop")
data class MyAwesome(
    var name: String = ""
)
```

I don't find a way to make the object immutable, all properties must be `var`. Is there a better way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Immutable @ConfigurationProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137932/immutable-configurationproperties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Spring Boot 2.2, we can use the `@ConstructorBinding` annotation to bind our configuration properties.

This essentially means that @ConfigurationProperties-annotated classes may now be **immutable**.

The `@ConstructorBinding` annotation indicates that configuration properties should be bound via constructor arguments rather than by calling setters

It's important to emphasize that to use the constructor binding, we need to explicitly enable our configuration class either with `@EnableConfigurationProperties` or with `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan`

If you don't have config class you can add it above the main application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyAwesome::class)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.awesome.prop")
data class MyAwesome(
    val name: String
)
```

then for instance in your configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyAwesome::class)
class MyConfig(private val myAwesome: MyAwesome) {}
```